# how to read/write mp3 ID3 Popularimeter in c#?

Tags: c#, mp3, id3

I tried UltraID3Lib to read my ID3 Tags in C#, no Problem.
But how can I read the rating filed (POPM)?
The API has an entry for "ID3v23PopularimeterFrame" but i don't know how to use it.

Please help me ;)
Thx, Ta

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, if you have mid3v2 installed

`mid3v2 --list-raw file.mp3 | grep POPM`

shows you file POPM informations